# Validate DTO in controller when passing data to service

Tags: mongodb, typescript, validation, nestjs, dto

I am trying to insert a validation into PUT request(to update some data stored in MongoDB):

**DTO:**

```
export enum reportFields {
    'startDate',
    'targetDateOfCompletion',
    'duration',
}


export class updateScheduleDto {
    @IsOptional()
    @IsString()
    readonly frequency?: string;

    @IsOptional()
    @IsArray()
    @IsEmail({}, { each: true })
    @IsString({ each: true })
    readonly emails?: string[];

    @IsOptional()
    @IsEnum(reportFields, { each: true })
    @IsArray()
    @IsString({ each: true })
    readonly reportFields?: string[];

    @IsOptional()
    @Type(() => Number)
    @IsNumber()
    updatedAt?: number;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Put('reports/:id/schedule')
async updateScheduleData(
    @Param('id') id: string,
    @Body(new ValidationPipe()) updateData: updateScheduleDto,
) {
    return this.reportService.updateScheduleData(id, updateData);
}
```

**Service:**

```
 async updateScheduleData(id: string, updateData: updateScheduleDto) {
        try {
            updateData.updatedAt = this.utils.getCurrentTime();
            const newData = await this.reportScheduleModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
                id,
                updateData,
                {
                    new: true,
                },
            );

            console.log(`Data has been updated to ${newData}`);
            return newData;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('>>>' + error);
        }
    }
```

But the validation not working over the keys. If I pass a non-valid key(like below) in the body object, even then the program executes without any error, how do I fix this? What am I missing?

```
{
    "emaaaalls":["randomemail123@gmail.com"]
}
```

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. My configuration is the same as in the other answers. I am not sure why, but the error is never thrown - not even in the catch event for the findByIdAndUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the options `{ forbidUnknownValues: true }` to the `ValidationPipe`. This will make `class-validator` throw an error when unknown values are passed in. [You can read through the options here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#using-the-built-in-validationpipe)

Comment: I added it now. But I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: You may also need `forbidNonWhitelisted` ass another option

Comment: Tried this too. Still, the program executes without throwing any Error. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you recompiling the server after changes? How are you re-starting things?

Comment: Yeah the server automatically restarts after every change

Comment: Sometimes I've seen issues wth `incremental: true`. Try deleting the dist and restarting the server. Those options should do what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can make `whitelist: true` in `ValidationPipe` options.

> When set to true, this will automatically remove non-whitelisted properties (those without any decorator in the validation class).

you can read more about this https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#stripping-properties